# I have an error creating a top down shooter C++ project in Unreal, Compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-engine, unreal-engine4, rider

I get an error when trying to create a top-down shooter c++ project in Unreal. I think it might have something to do with paging files but I'm not sure. I have visual studio 2022 community installed for the compiler and use Rider for Unreal Engine as an actual IDE, it's the default. If anybody knows how to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

The Error Message:

```
The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Rider?
    
    Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Unreal Projects/Survival/Survival.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
    Creating makefile for SurvivalEditor (no existing makefile)
    @progress push 5%
    Parsing headers for SurvivalEditor
      Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Unreal Projects\Survival\Survival.uproject" "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Unreal Projects\Survival\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalEditor\Development\SurvivalEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_UHT.txt" -installed
    LogInit: Display: Loading text-based GConfig....
    Reflection code generated for SurvivalEditor in 10.9429744 seconds
    @progress pop
    Building SurvivalEditor...
    Using Visual Studio 2019 14.30.30705 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705) and Windows 10.0.19041.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
    Building 13 actions with 4 processes...
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0%
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 8%
      [1/13] Default.rc2
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 15%
      [2/13] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.cpp
      Detected compiler newer than Visual Studio 2019, please update min version checking in WindowsPlatformCompilerSetup.h
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 23%
      [3/13] SurvivalGameMode.cpp
      c1xx: error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
      c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
      
      
      c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
      c1xx: fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 31%
      [4/13] SurvivalCharacter.gen.cpp
      c1xx: error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
      c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
      
      
      c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
      c1xx: fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 38%
      [5/13] Survival.cpp
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 46%
      [6/13] SurvivalPlayerController.gen.cpp
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 54%
      [7/13] Survival.init.gen.cpp
      c1xx: error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
      c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
      
      
      c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
      c1xx: fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 62%
      [8/13] SurvivalPlayerController.cpp
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 69%
      [9/13] SurvivalGameMode.gen.cpp
      @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 77%
      [10/13] SurvivalCharacter.cpp
```

Comment: Increase the size of your page file...

Comment: Visual studio 2022 isn't officially supported, your output is even having a moan : "please update min version checking in WindowsPlatformCompilerSetup.h". Updating that may even solve the problem, but I'd say your better off back dating to 2019. (The issue could also be how much ram you're running, but if it's at-least 8gb, it really shouldn't be an issue. If you aren't using much ram, then increasing the amount of v memory for the heal should help too. But will increase compile times.)

Comment: My computer has 8gb of RAM and 8gb of paging file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just too many symbols or template instantiations.

Use /Zm to adjust the compiler heap limit and follow other recommendations here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1076?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 can produce the error:

```
7>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
7>c1xx : message : the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
7>c1xx : message : please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
7>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
```

even on computers having a lot of RAM (e.g. 64Gb) and big page file, if a number of projects compile in parallel, see:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-C3859:-Failed-to-create-virtual-me/10056333

According to Microsoft response there this error can happen more frequently in Visual Studio 2022 compared to Visual Studio 2019 because by default VS2022 uses 64-bit build tools, which consume more memory on their operations and create larger precompiled header file compared to 32-bit tools.

The suggested solution is to keep using 32-bit build, which are still included in Visual Studio 2022. To do it in command line:

```
msbuild ... /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x86
```

In project (`.vcxproj`)/properties(`.props`) file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>
  </PropertyGroup>
```